# Sticky div inside a TD Works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, sticky

I created a table with a JS script and this is like a simplified version of the result.

In this table the `<thead>` is and should be sticky and works fine in Firefox.

The problem is 'foo'. This div should be sticky inside the  and works fine in Chrome but not Firefox.

I no longer use flex and overflow but still does not work. I've also read that the display:table should work fine but i use rowSpan and Its not fully supported.

Does anyone know how can i fix my problem and get the same results with both browsers?

Fyi the script creates a sticky custom element without shadowroot which is what is inside the .

```css
thead {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

thead th {
  background: #d24d57;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: silver;
  height: 3em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.divSticky {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.subcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 120px;
}

.text {
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 70%;
  color: purple;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 878px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:700px;">
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowSpan="3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr style="height:700px;">
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="divSticky">
            <div class="subcontainer">
              <div class="text">
                foo
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>xx</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<tr style="height:700px;vertical-align:top">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. vertical-align:top makes the foo in the place i want but does not do the effect that happens in chrome.

Comment: What i want to archive is the position:sticky works, so when i scroll down  i can see the div ultill i reach the end of the <td> . 
What i need is the 'foo' to have like a  position:fixed but only inside the td (sticky). You can run the snippet in Chrome and scroll down to see how foo follows your scrolling.